# What is the difference between classification and regression metrices such as accuracy and MSE?

Tags: regression, statistics, mathematics

What is the difference between classification metrics such as accuracy and regression metrics such as MPE? & Why can’t accuracy be used as regression metric?

Comment: [I thought I explained this yesterday.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/115978/73930) Is there something about my answer left unclear? If so, please comment there to ask for clarification. // Do you mean MSE or MPE? You’ve written each of those once. // You’ve posted a number of related questions in the past few days. While that’s totally fine (and really preferred to writing one post with many questions), you may get more quality answers by giving the equations for your statistics/metrics of interest in order to make sure everyone is on the same page about their definitions.

Comment: The last point is especially applicable to [your post about $R^2$](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115947/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-r2-coefficient-of-determination), where you have been linked to a resource that gives at least five ways of calculating $R^2$, all of which have their reasons to be used.